# Input value must contain number higher than 5

Tags: form-validation, contact-us, contact-form, input

In my contactform I want to display a inputfield, that may only contain a number, higher than 5.

How can I achieve that?

My current code is:

```
        <li>
            <div class="field">
            <label for="gewensteaantal" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Requested qty') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input name="gewensteaantal" id="gewensteaantal" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Requested qty') ?>" value="" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
            </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: higher than 5 digits or higher than 5 ie (6, 7 and so on ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom validation class 'validate-value-greater-than-5' and add following script in form javascript.

```
Validation.add('validate-value-greater-than-5', 'Please enter a value greater than 5.', function(v) {
    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || (v > 5);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to just use **type=number** in input.

```
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="6">
```

Now user have input 6 or higher than 6 to submit form otherwise display error with no form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class :

```
class="input-text validate-length maximum-length-50 minimum-length-5 validate-greater-than-zero validate-number validate-digits required-entry"
```

This will accept only digits and numbers with minimum of 5 and maximum of 50 length

These classes "validate-length maximum-length-50 minimum-length-5" are responsilble to handle the max and min length

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work. The minimum length should be 5. Which is not the number, but the characters. So than a number must be at least a 5 digit number.